# Is there a function, that would return "" when input ref is empty, and its contents if it is not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

IMO Excel has weird treatment of empty Cells.

I am building a complex array formula. One of the referenced ranges contain cells, that may, or may not be empty, and if not empty, they can contain both numeric values and strings.

What function can I use, to get the value of the cell if the cell is not empty, and "" (or anything other non-numeric, e.g. `#N/A`) if the cell is empty?

I want to get something like this working:

```
=MIN(OFFSET(<column vector that contains text, numbers and empty cells>;<row vector of indices>-1;0))
```

This form of formula returns an `#ARG` error, as was explained in the answer to [Why this array formula doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820256/why-this-array-formula-doesnt-work).

But when I prefix the `OFFSET` with `N`, it transforms any empty cell into `0`, so the net result is `0` (unless there are negative numbers in the column vector).

```
=MIN(L(OFFSET(<column vector>;<row vector of indices>-1;0)))
```

Is there any formula, that only dereferences the reference returned by `OFFSET` preserving the "emptyness" of the empty cell? Or maybe there is an alternate way of solving the problem, like

```
=MIN(IF(OFFSET(<column vector>;<row vector of indices>-1;0)="",L(OFFSET(<column vector>;<row vector of indices>-1;0)),""))
```

(This example also fails with `#ARG`, because, as I understand, I need to dereference the array reference for the `=` test as well).

If it is at all possible, I prefer to keep with Excel 2007 set of built-in functions. And no VBA.

I would accept any solution, that uses constant number of cells irregardless of the size of each input array.

---

EDIT:

As a side remark I wonder what is wrong with the arrays returned by `OFFSET` anyway? This simple example works perfectly:

[image]

...while the array returned by `OFFSET` somehow wants to be alone in the formula.

Comment: `ISBLANK`? http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isblank.php

Comment: Just to understand, putting this in the simplest form possible, you want, for example `MIN(A1:A10)` for example where the cells in A1:A10 might be numeric of empty or have text?

Comment: @JohnBustos I'm afraid no. I need something that works with an array formula. I don't know how to simplify more the example in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be another option but I don't see it at the moment.....

You can filter out zeroes by using an IF like this

`=MIN(IF(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0))<>0,N(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0))))`

but that won't distinguish between any actual zeroes in your range and those produced when the N function encounters blanks or text

**Edit**

This version should work

`=MIN(IF(COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1))+LEN(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1))),"",N(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1))))`

Perhaps not completely relevant here but the problem is finding functions that can deal with the "array of references" returned by OFFSET with this type of setup - `N` and `T` work as shown here and also `COUNTBLANK`. Other functions that can be used on the OFFSET output are `SUBTOTAL` and `COUNTIF`. Note that `COUNTBLANK` (along with `SUBTOTAL` and `COUNTIF`) can work on ranges while `T` and `N` will only work with single values - if the latter functions are applied to ranges they simply look at the first value in the range - because of that I was able to use `OFFSET` without the "height" parameter but you need that with `COUNTBLANK` (and it's a good habit to get in to so `OFFSET` should have the final 1 as here

=OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1)

Comment: Yes. I thought about this solution before. Unfortunately zeroes are actually quite common in my production input data vector...

Comment: I think, that your lead is good, the only problem is how to tell apart zeroes and empty cells in array. I'll make it another question.

Comment: Ups.. to late ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842384/is-there-any-formula-that-can-accept-array-of-references-and-can-tell-if-the-r Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: I thought that putting the question in different way can attract more attention.

Comment: No problem - it's just that you might have to explain the logic each time - sometimes better to stick with one question.....

Comment: I've found partial answer to this problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842384/is-there-any-formula-that-can-accept-array-of-references-and-can-tell-if-the-r/19843893#19843893
 What is left, is to how to return the actual contents rather than the 1 or 0. The normal methods don't work.

Comment: Good find with COUNTBLANK! I didn't think of that - it's a bit clunky but if you combine that with checking whether T function returns a non blank (i.e. text) then you can get the correct MIN - I edited my answer

Comment: This formula ignores the text values (and puts "") in place of them, but I think that I can live with that. The problem is, when the input vector is numeric encoded as string. It gets ignored, too.

Comment: OK. Here is the remedy: IF(COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1));"";IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1)));T(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1));N(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),$C4:$G4-1,0,1))))

This formula doesn't ignore text and, consequently, numbers encoded as string.

Comment: And, the formula on my last comment, is what really, 100% works. It works, and I hardly believe it. I hope, that when I wake up tomorrow the formula will still be there and it all was not a dream :-) !!! In my opinion you earned much much more, than just one simple +1.

Comment: That doesn't work for me - did you transcribe it correctly? What is the second IF doing, there's no valid test there....

Comment: interesting analyisis - i also posted another alternative as i believe the proposed answer can be simplified using the `CELL` function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider in B1:

**=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"nothing there",A1)**

So if A1 contains the formula:

=""

Then B1 will also display the null.

Comment: You little oversimplified my question. I need something, that will work with array formula. But putting your idea into `=MIN(IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET(<column vector>;<row of indices>-1;0)),"",OFFSET(<column vector>;<row of indices>-1;0))` fails. I need something to de-reference the result of the `OFFSET` formula. Something along the line of `N`, but valid for empty cells and strings.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
=MIN(CELL("contents",OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$2),N(INDEX($C4:$G4-1,)),0)))
```

**Note**: The `N(INDEX(...))` part is a trick used to enforce array evaluation.