# Check if the referenced cell inside an array is `0` or is empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find some way of telling apart zeroes and empty cells in e.g. the results of the array value of OFFSET function. In the included illustration, I'd like to have empty string in the cells `D4` and `D6`.

[image]

The `B5` equals `=""`, and `B7` is genuinely empty. I don't want to distinguish between these cases.

- I'm interested only in formula solutions that take constant number of
  cells for each row of index vector.
- No VBA.
- As a last resort I will
  accept a solution that uses the popular MoreFunc Excel package or
  other free and publicly available Excel add-on.

I know how to do that
   using [RExcel](http://www.statconn.com/products.html#RExcel), but this is too sophisticated, and there will be
   issues/difficulties with cell dependence during recalculations (not to mention installation of R and "friends").

---

Here is a related question of mine:

[Is there a function, that would return “” when input ref is empty, and its contents if it is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840989/is-there-a-function-that-would-return-when-input-ref-is-empty-and-its-conte/19841772?noredirect=1#comment29507329_19841772)

Comment: One other possibility... instead of OFFSET use: `=INDEX(B3:B8,N(IF({1},C13:C17)))`. This will not convert blanks to zeros so you can use inside `MIN()` to return 1 (not 0). [See also linked post for another alternative based on `CELL` function].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found one. Actually it was very simple.

```
=COUNTBLANK(<array of refernces>)
```

[image]